# Cant change javascript popupbox widht height and background colors

Tags: javascript, css

Im make javascript popup box, but i cant change width, height and background how can i do it?

```
.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-content {
    border: 0;
    padding: 2em 3em;
    background:#e5e5e5;
    overflow: auto;
    zoom: 1; 
}
```

---

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                $(function inPageLoad() {
                    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoaded(function () {

                        //btnSave and btnUpdate clicks
                        $(document).on('click', '#<%=btnSave.ClientID %> , #<%=btnUpdate.ClientID %>', function (e) {
                            e.preventDefault();
                            alert("x");
                            $('<div></div>').appendTo('body')
                              .html('<div><h6>Yes or No?</h6></div>')
                              .dialog({
                                  modal: true, title: 'message', zIndex: 10000, autoOpen: true,
                                  width: 'auto', resizable: false,
                                  buttons: {
                                      Yes: function () {
                                          //doFunctionForYes();
                                          $(this).dialog("close");
                                      },
                                      No: function () {
                                          //doFunctionForNo();
                                          $(this).dialog("close");
                                      }
                                  },
                                  close: function (event, ui) {
                                      $(this).remove();
                                  }
                              });

             });
                    });
                });

            $(document).ready(inPageLoad);

        </script>
```

Comment: Please describe in more detail, how you want to change the width and where you are stuck at.

Comment: sir i need to change this popup, im not idea how can i  do it, im try to more time,

Comment: No need to use sir. It seems though that you did not understand me properly. I will try to help you somehow. You can add with, height ect. in your javascript. You are basically creating the pop up through that and can just change its style there. When you do this thing here > $('<div></div>').appendTo('body') Just add a class to the div container making it.
$('<div class="popup"></div>').appendTo('body')
That way you can use js to change its stye by directing it to the class.